# How to initialize PHP constructor fields in Visual Studio Code

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code, If I have the following PHP Class

```php
<?php

use ...

class MyHelper
{
  private $logger;

  public function __construct(LoggerInterace $logger) {
  //code...

  }
}
```

..Is there a way I can tell that constructor to initialize `$this->logger = $logger` without manually typing that out every time?

Comment: use it as a class property instead of a dependency

Comment: Are you asking how to have VScode add it for you?

Comment: @AbraCadaver yes - exactly.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you can use this [PHP Constructor](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MehediDracula.php-constructor&ssr=false) Visual Studio Code package to generate class constructor with variable and it's property.
Just install and use shortcut key `Ctrl+Shift+P` then command **Insert Constructor Property**. That's it. It will generate what you expect.

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
class IMyHelper
{
    private $logger;

    public function __construct(LoggerInterace $logger) {
        $this->logger = $logger
    }
}
```

And then

```
class MyHelper extends IMyHelper
{
    // And if here __construct does not exist 
    // php runs constructor from IMyHelper
    // if i remember good :)

  function OtherMethod(){

  }
}
```

In visual code search plugins but from what vs may know what variable you need inicialize ;)

Comment: Please don't vandalize your answer. If you want to delete it, just delete it.